# How do I install eyecon's datepicker on Grails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails, datepicker

I'm trying to implement [eyecon's datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) on my Grails project. So I put this in my ApplicationResources.groovy:

```
datepicker {
    resource url: 'datepicker/css/datepicker.css'
    resource url: 'datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'
}
```

And then I put this in my main.gsp:

```
<r:require module="datepicker" />
```

And then this is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="gray-bg">
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Select date" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, this is the Javascript:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

But nothing's working...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add jquery to dependencies like this:

```
datepicker {
    dependsOn 'jquery'
    resource url: 'datepicker/css/datepicker.css'
    resource url: 'datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'
}
```

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. It worked when I used the <link href...> and the <script src=....> but that would be a little inefficient since I'd have to put it on all of my .gsp